# Symfony 4 .{_format} not working

Tags: php, symfony, routes, frameworks, symfony4

so I've got this route

```
 /**
 * @Route("/user/{id}/diary.{_format}",
 *     defaults={"_format": "json"},
 *     requirements={
 *        "id": "\d+",
 *        "_format": "csv|json"
 *     }
 * )
 */
public function showRaw(User $user, Request $request)
{

}
```

So when I acccess /user/1/diary it works with whatever I write in the function but when I try to access /user/1/diary.json or /user/1/diary.csv I get an 404 error, so I guess the route parameters are not matching properly.

I would like to, depending on what the format is, return a diferent response but until now I can't get the format.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can see routes from command `php bin/console router:debug`?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev yeah, I solved it already, the problem was with the index.php in the url. So this route http://localhost/user/1/diary.json didn't work but this one http://localhost/index.php/user/1/diary.json works very strange :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using PHP's built-in development server without an explicit routing script:

```
[saizferri:public]$  php -S localhost:5000
```

or:

```
[saizferri:symfony_project]$  php -S localhost:5000 -t public/
```

When run like this, PHP processes each request by looking in the current directory (or root given with `-t`) for the requested resource. If it isn't found [and PHP thinks it is a file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.13/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L2171)—as it did in the case of `/user/1/diary.csv`—PHP will return HTTP 404; otherwise, [PHP will search](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.13/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L1348) for `index.php` or `index.html`, and, if either is found, it is served with `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` set appropriately—this is why you were able to view `/user/1/diary`. (See [the description](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) in the manual.)

Instead, tell PHP to route all requests through `public/index.php`:

```
php -S localhost:<port> public/index.php
```